# What does it mean when a program runs fine on its own but when in debug mode it gives a SIGSEGV segmentation fault

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I have a program that runs fine on its own consistently and I am trying to learn to use a debugger. When I run it with the debugger (in Code::Blocks) I get a SIGSEGV notification. Does anyone know what would cause a problem with these symptoms?

Here is the code:

```
    font = new Picture("font.png");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,font->texID);
    int w,h;//because it requires ints
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &w);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &h);
    fontTexW = w;
    fontTexH = h;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,NULL);
    std::ifstream widths;
    widths.open("fontWidths.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::string num;
    for(int i = 0;i < 95;i++)
    {
        std::getline(widths,line);
        int j = 0;
        num = "";
        while(line[j] != ',') //this is where the arrow stops
        {
            num.push_back(line[j]);
            j++;
        }
        fontLocs.push_back(Point(atoi(num.c_str()),0));
        num = "";
        j++;//avoid comma
        while(j < line.size())
        {
            num.push_back(line[j]);
            j++;
        }
        fontWidths.push_back(atoi(num.c_str()));
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I just realized that this is the first time my program would try to read from something not loaded with SOIL (OpenGL Texture Loading). Could it have to do with file Loading?

Comment: Did you already use the debugger to step through your program and identify, where exactly your program throws? You could well have hit some undefined behavior, that behaves differently for release and debug mode.

Comment: You failed to check if `line` is empty.  Accessing `line[0]` on an empty line is undefined behavior.

Comment: You also refused to check if the file `"fontWidths.txt"` was opened successfully.  Overall, your program makes assumptions that probably proved to be false when run in debug mode such as a file being opened successfully, there are 95 lines of text, whether a line has data, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The things you point out are true but. The program runs perfectly when it is not in debug mode so my question is what is different about debug mode and how can I get it to load files correctly

Comment: @OctoDragon "The program runs perfectly when it is not in debug mode"  <-- that statement is probably false.  It's more likely that there is an error in your code, and bad things are happening, but outside of debug mode the symptoms are non-obvious.  (e.g. some memory is getting corrupted somewhere, but in such a way that it does not crash your program -- for now)

Comment: @0ctoDragon - `The program runs perfectly when it is not in debug mode`  Welcome to the world of C++, where programs that seem to run "perfectly" can have internal bugs.  C++ has a concept called `undefined behavior` -- something most other languages do not have.  What that means is that if you're program corrupts memory, accesses an invalid index, uses an uninitialized variable, etc.  then *anything* can occur *including* "working perfectly".  You *always* must check whether a function fails or not, *always* ensure that array elements you are accessing are within bounds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the debugger can optimize your std::string so that size() is not going to work with it as well as before. try omitting the size() function and check again

Comment: Is there a way to turn off this type of debugger optimization

Comment: not familiar with code::blocks but using GNU GDB you should compile with the -o% before (where % is 1,2,3 or S). e.g.: gcc -o3 -o test test.c

Comment: @OctoDragon - Why do you think a program as trivial as yours would trip up a well-tested compiler that is used by thousands of individuals and companies?  The bug is in your code somewhere, unless you can prove it is an optimization error by producing the assembly listing.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is due to size function?

Comment: Found it here:http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,16772.msg114299.html#msg114299